# Sum fields from different tables per userID

Tags: php, mysql, sum

**Need your help.**
php, mysql

I have the following project.

I have two tables

```
**table 1**

user_id    Plan
1           5
1           7  
2           5
2           9
3           7
1           9


**table 2**
Plan        Price
5           100
7           200
9           300
```

I must find the total cost of plans selected by one user
eg user_id = 2 must pay 400

I have already the following code, but this one adds the Price of all Plans in database in the above example total cost = 600
What am I doing wrong? :(

```
$totalcost = NULL;

$sql = "select SUM(Plan.Cost) as ANSWER FROM Plan";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        $totalcost = mysql_fetch_row($result);


          $sql = "select * FROM Plan";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $Plan = array();

        if (is_resource($result)) {
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $Plan[] = $row;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `user_id` in your query, like:

```
$user_id = 2; // or get it from $_GET, $_POST...    
$sql = "select SUM(Plan.Cost) as ANSWER
FROM Plan, Users 
WHERE Users.Plan = Plan.Plan AND Users.user_id = $user_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use LEFT JOIN in your query, so you can make something like this:

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.plan, SUM(table2.cost) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.plan=table2.plan WHERE table1.user_id = $user_id;
```

this way you can fetch results in 1 query and make database do all the work instead of looping through data in functions etc.

[SQL left join tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)